# Source Code to add a popup Date Picker control using JavaScript in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I need the proper steps/Source Code to add a POPUP Date Picer control using JavaScript in ASP.NET

Comment: Have you tried googling something? Anything that let me know what have you tried?

Comment: ya i have tried ,but coding doesn't support to download, and few codes/files are missing in few cases..

Comment: ya , i got it Thanks for u'r guidance,Limo

Answer (score 2):

Use [JQuery Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/).

> The jQuery UI Datepicker is a highly
>   configurable plugin that adds
>   datepicker functionality to your
>   pages. You can customize the date
>   format and language, restrict the
>   selectable date ranges and add in
>   buttons and other navigation options
>   easily.
>
> By default, the datepicker calendar
>   opens in a small overlay onFocus and
>   closes automatically onBlur or when a
>   date is selected. For an inline
>   calendar, simply attach the datepicker
>   to a div or span.
>
> You can use keyboard shortcuts to
>   drive the datepicker.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using one of these:

- [Calendar Extender](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/Calendar/Calendar.aspx) control in *AJAX Control Toolkit*
- [jQuery DatePicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)

An example for the `CalendarExtender` control in the *AJAX Control Toolkit*:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtDate" Enabled="false" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" 
    CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="VG_SAVE"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="DateExtender" runat="server" 
    TargetControlID="TxtDate" />
```